# Iterative substitute in R

Tags: r, recursion, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to create aliases for a formula.

Some data to start with:

```
data = data.table(C = runif(3), B = runif(3), N = runif(3), G = runif(3))
```

Simple formula

```
formula = substitute(C ~ I(B / N) + B + G * I(B / N))
lm(formula, data)
```

Now let's create simple alias for `B / N` and call it `avg_BN`

```
aliases = list(
    avg_BN = quote(B / N)
)
formula_primitive = substitute(C ~ I(avg_BN) + B + G * I(avg_BN), aliases)
lm(formula_primitive, data)
```

**My problem comes, when I make complex aliases, which use other aliases in their definitions (`inverse_BN`, `super_duper`):**

```
aliases_complex = list(
    avg_BN = quote(B / N),
    inverse_BN = quote(1 / avg_BN), #I use alias in alias
    super_duper = quote(avg_BN / inverse_BN) #I use alias in alias
)
formula_complex = substitute(C ~ I(avg_BN) + B + G * I(inverse_BN) + super_duper, aliases_complex)
lm(formula_complex, data)
```

**How I can make iterative substitute?** I thought initially to split definitions of aliases to primitives and complex, evaluate first primitives and then go to complex. But in fact within complex the same issue arises, because it can have link to another complex, which linked to another and so on. Thus, I need some kind of reduce of substitution. I feel like I am creating yet another bicycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bquote`?

```
e1 <- new.env()
e1$avg_BN <- quote(B / N)
e1$inverse_BN <- bquote(1 / .(avg_BN), e1)
e1$super_duper <- bquote(.(avg_BN) / .(inverse_BN), e1) 

formula_complex <- bquote(C ~ I(.(avg_BN)) + B + G * I(.(inverse_BN)) + .(super_duper), e1)
#C ~ I(B/N) + B + G * I(1/(B/N)) + B/N/(1/(B/N))
```

Comment: plus one, you could also use `with` to avoid repeatedly accessing the environment with `$`

Comment: @Roland thx for the answer. I see some inconvenience with current approach. With bquote I will have to use different syntax for aliases and real names.
`e1$inverse_BN <- bquote(1 / .(avg_BN) + B + N + primitive, e1)`
Thus, `primitive` is not substituted.

Comment: I actually view this as an advantage.